# How to implement generic error handling that works with forkJoin in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, rxjs6

I have an app where I've implemented error handling according to the official Angular 6 tutorial in rest.service.ts

```
... 
       return this.http.get(url).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error("An error occurred:", error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` + `body was: ${error.error}`
      );
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError(error.error);
  }
```

My problem is that I also need to use forkJoin, and with this error handling, forkJoin hangs. Error handling in forkJoin tutorials looks like this:

```
throwError('This will error').pipe(catchError(error => of(error))
```

How could I create a generic error handler that also works with forkJoin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out that there's no need to change the error handling in the rest service,
I just needed to pipe catchError to the observables pushed in the array to be passed to forkJoin.

```
this.observables.push(
    this.rest.get(endpoint, null).pipe(catchError(error => of(error)))
  );
```